# connect to azure ms sqlserver in spring boot application

Tags: sql-server, azure, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to the azure ms sqlserver database. I have setup these properties in the application.properties file, but I get exceptions, connection timed out.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxserver.database.windows.net:port;DatabaseName=xxxdb;user=xxxadmin@xxxserver;password=passwd;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=xxxadmin@xxxserver
spring.datasource.password=passwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I get this exception:

```
2016-02-16 23:36:46.645 ERROR 7840 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Login timed out.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:433) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past the jtds driver had problems with azure sql due to the driver having problems negotiating the SSL encryption handshake. 
The recommended driver is the Microsoft one.

more info here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple-windows/

Comment: but there is no maven repo for the microsoft sql driver. I have to save it locally to access it, but if I have to move it production environment, how can I do it ?